# Terraform for loop is not using variable names

Tags: terraform

I have this expression in the terraform console:

```
jsonencode([for x in ["a", "b"] : { x = "hello" }])
```

It gives this output:

```
[{"x":"hello"},{"x":"hello"}]
```

Why it is interpreting "x" literally and not as a variable? This is my desired output:

```
[{"a":"hello"},{"b":"hello"}]
```

Comment: Which version of Terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because unquoted strings in this context are considered as [map's keys](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/types.html#map):

> The keys in a map must be strings; they can be left **unquoted if they are a valid identifier**, but must be quoted otherwise.

If you want to treat `x` as variable you either use it in **quotes** or **parentheses**:

```
jsonencode([for x in ["a", "b"] : { (x) = "hello" }])
```

or

```
jsonencode([for x in ["a", "b"] : { "${x}" = "hello" }])
```

Comment: I verified both methods work with 0.14.2. However the second method generates a warning (which I disagree with) `Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated`

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. Not sure, you disagree with the warning or the method itself?

Comment: The warning. In this case you must enclose with quotes. I am hoping one of the Terraform developers takes note as they move to 1.0

Comment: Indeed, the second example is using a deprecated feature that happens to get the desired behavior, but the first example (using parentheses) is [the approach recommended in the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/types.html#maps-objects).